# How can I get all sequences in an Oracle database?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, sequence, toad

Is there any command that I can run so that I can get all the sequences? 
I am using Oracle 11g. I am using Toad for Oracle to connect to it. I can visually see the sequences in Toad, but I like to know the command line for it.

Answer (score 157, accepted):

```
select sequence_owner, sequence_name from dba_sequences;


DBA_SEQUENCES -- all sequences that exist 
ALL_SEQUENCES  -- all sequences that you have permission to see 
USER_SEQUENCES  -- all sequences that you own
```

Note that since you are, by definition, the owner of all the sequences returned from `USER_SEQUENCES`, there is no `SEQUENCE_OWNER` column in `USER_SEQUENCES`.

Comment: I am getting the following error:
Error at line 1
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

Comment: This one worked for me: select * from all_sequences;

Comment: Yes, that's why I mentioned all three views, DBA/ALL/USER_SEQUENCES.  Everyone has access to USER_ and ALL_ views, but not necessarily DBA_ views.  It depends on your local security policies.  To be clear, if you don't have access to DBA_ views, then you really can't answer the question "How do I get all the sequences that exist in the database?"

Comment: `USER_SEQUENCES` doesn't have the column 'SEQUENCE_OWNER' so the query would result in `select * from USER_sequences;`  or `select sequence_name from USER_sequences;`

Comment: That's correct, Lorenzo.  That's why I actually mentioned that it my answer.  See the last line.

Answer (score 51):

You may not have permission to dba_sequences.  So you can always just do:

```
select * from user_sequences;
```

Comment: No, you cannot.  The question was "Is there any command that I can run so that I can get all the sequences?"  USER_SEQUENCES only gives you the sequences you *own*.  ALL_SEQUENCES only gives you the sequences you have permissions on.  To correctly (and fully) answer the question, you *need* DBA_SEQUENCES.  If you don't have access to DBA_SEQUENCES, you don't have any way to answer the question.